# How to configure basic network in virt-manager

Tags: virtual-machine, virt-manager, libvirt

I'm scratching my head here, trying to follow a basic Red Hat study guide.

I have a centos 7 host and installed a centos 7 guest os with virt-manager/qemu.

I configured a static IP of 192.168.122.50 for the guest and I can't get it to access the internet through my host or even ping it from the host.

Can someone give me a simple guide. I'm not trying to do anything complicated. Do I need to set up a bridge between host and guest?

EDIT: I got it working and the answer is quite boring.

I just deleted the guest OS and started again with stock networking settings and worked from there. I eventually got the required static IP and I think I might have missed out specifying the gateway address and DNS server the first time round. These are both 192.168.122.1 and my static IP was 192.168.122.50 but the DHCP range was 192.168.122.2 - 192.168.122.254 out of an available subnet of 192.168.122.0/24. I expected that my static IP (50) might get in the way of the DHCP range but I think that manually specifying the gateway/DNS and static IP prevented libvirt from getting address conflicts and I was able to boot the VM with DNS and internet access via NAT through the host! :-D

Comment: [This guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Virtualization_Deployment_and_Administration_Guide/sect-Network_configuration-Bridged_networking.html) might help. You need a bridge on the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes setup a bridge. If I remember the guides right, this is what redhat and SUSE tell you there.